# ERROR in The given rootPath undefined is not a file of the program While Upgrade To Angular Ver. 12

Tags: angular, angular12, ng-sortable, angular-sortablejs

### While Upgrade My App From Angular 11 To 12 , After Run `ng update @angular/core@12 @angular/cli@12` , and run yarn start , the following error displayed :
[Error After Run Angular in version 12][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wGim.png

Package.json

```
    {
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^3.0.0-beta.0",
    "@agm/drawing": "^3.0.0-beta.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.13",
    "@angular/common": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/compiler": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/core": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/forms": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^11.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/router": "^12.2.16",
    "@aspnet/signalr": "^1.0.2",
    "@devexpress/analytics-core": "^19.2.4",
    "@fancyapps/fancybox": "^3.1.25",
    "@kolkov/angular-editor": "^0.13.1",
    "@ng-plus/signature-pad": "0.0.5",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^5.2.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-charts": "^4.1.4",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-common": "^1.2.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "^4.2.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^4.2.4",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": "^3.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^4.6.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^6.4.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^2.0.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^2.0.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-layout": "^4.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-menu": "^2.0.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-pdf-export": "^2.0.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "^3.0.5",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-tooltip": "^2.1.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-treeview": "^4.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-upload": "^5.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-data-query": "^1.5.2",
    "@progress/kendo-drawing": "^1.6.0",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "4.43.0",
    "abp-ng2-module": "^3.2.3",
    "abp-web-resources": "^3.8.4",
    "angular-oauth2-oidc": "^4.0.2",
    "angular-sortablejs": "^2.6.0",
    "angular2-counto": "^1.2.5",
    "angular2-uuid": "^1.1.1",
    "animate.css": "3.6.1",
    "autosize": "^4.0.0",
    "b64-to-blob": "^1.2.19",
    "block-ui": "^2.70.1",
    "blueimp-file-upload": "^9.22.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "bootstrap-daterangepicker": "^3.0.3",
    "bootstrap-hover-dropdown": "^2.2.1",
    "bootstrap-markdown": "^2.10.0",
    "bootstrap-maxlength": "^1.6.0",
    "bootstrap-notify": "^3.1.3",
    "bootstrap-select": "1.13.1",
    "bootstrap-switch": "^3.3.4",
    "bootstrap-timepicker": "^0.5.2",
    "bootstrap-touchspin": "^4.2.5",
    "bootstrap4-datetimepicker": "^5.2.3",
    "bower": "*",
    "chart.js": "^2.6.0",
    "chartist": "^0.11.0",
    "clone": "^2.1.2",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "compare-versions": "^3.4.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.7",
    "css-star-rating": "^1.2.4",
    "css-toggle-switch": "^4.0.3",
    "d3": "^5.5.0",
    "detect-zoom": "^1.0.2",
    "devexpress-dashboard": "^19.2.4",
    "devexpress-reporting-angular": "^19.2.4",
    "devextreme": "^19.2.4",
    "dropzone": "^5.5.1",
    "easy-pie-chart": "^2.1.7",
    "famfamfam-flags": "^1.0.0",
    "flot": "^0.8.0-alpha",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "gmaps": "^0.4.24",
    "inputmask": "^4.0.0",
    "ion-rangeslider": "^2.3.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "jquery-form": "^4.2.1",
    "jquery-migrate": "^3.0.0",
    "jquery-mousewheel": "^3.1.13",
    "jquery-slimscroll": "^1.3.8",
    "jquery-sparkline": "^2.4.0",
    "jquery-validation": "^1.15.1",
    "jquery.counterup": "^2.1.0",
    "jquery.flot.tooltip": "^0.9.0",
    "jquery.inputmask": "^3.3.4",
    "jquery.uniform": "^4.2.0",
    "jqueryui": "^1.11.1",
    "jqvmap": "^1.5.1",
    "js-cookie": "^2.1.4",
    "js-url": "^2.3.0",
    "json2": "*",
    "jstree": "^3.3.4",
    "karma": "^6.4.0",
    "localforage": "^1.7.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin": "^3.1.5",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.21",
    "morris.js": "^0.5.0",
    "mustache": "^2.3.0",
    "ng-recaptcha": "^4.0.0-beta.1",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.3.0",
    "ng2modules-easypiechart": "^0.0.4",
    "ng2modules-flot": "^0.0.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^9.0.0",
    "ngx-device-detector": "^1.4.5",
    "ngx-mask": "^6.1.3",
    "ngx-webcam": "^0.2.6",
    "pace-progress": "^1.0.2",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.5",
    "primeicons": "1.0.0-beta.10",
    "primeng": "6.0.2",
    "prismjs": "^1.15.0",
    "push.js": "1.0.7",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "rangeslider.js": "^2.3.1",
    "raphael": "^2.2.7",
    "rtl-detect": "^1.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.5",
    "sass": "^1.54.0",
    "select2": "^4.0.5",
    "select2-bootstrap-theme": "0.1.0-beta.10",
    "simple-line-icons": "^2.4.1",
    "socicon": "^3.0.5",
    "sortablejs": "^1.7.0",
    "spin.js": "^2.3.2",
    "summernote": "^0.8.6",
    "sweetalert": "^2.0.8",
    "tether": "^1.4.0",
    "timeago": "^1.6.1",
    "toastr": "^2.1.2",
    "topojson": "^3.0.2",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "typeahead.js": "^0.11.1",
    "underscore": "^1.9.1",
    "urijs": "^1.19.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "waypoints": "^4.0.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.18",
    "@angular/cli": "^12.2.18",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^12.2.16",
    "@angularclass/hmr": "^2.1.3",
    "@angularclass/hmr-loader": "^3.0.4",
    "@types/bootstrap": "^4.1.2",
    "@types/grecaptcha": "^2.0.35",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.5",
    "@types/jquery.blockui": "0.0.28",
    "@types/jstree": "^3.3.34",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.114",
    "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
    "@types/moment-timezone": "^0.5.6",
    "@types/morris.js": "^0.5.7",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/tether": "^1.4.4",
    "@types/toastr": "^2.1.33",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "^0.24.1",
    "nswag": "^11.17.21",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "typescript": "4.3.5",
    "yarn-upgrade-all": "^0.7.1"
  }
}
```

---

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015" , "es6", "dom" ],
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "esnext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@abp/*": [ "../node_modules/abp-ng2-module/dist/src/*" ],
      "@app/*": [ "./app/*" ],
      "@shared/*": [ "./shared/*" ],
      "@node_modules/*": [ "../node_modules/*" ],
      "@angular/*": [ "../node_modules/@angular/*" ]
    }
  },
  "files": [
    "main.ts",
    "polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "../src/**/*",
    "../node_modules/abp-ng2-module/**/*"
  ]
}
```

---

I`m tried to change angular-sortablejs to ngx-sortablejs , but while change it all modules and many component have a lot of errors

Comment: Any Advice ....

Answer (score 3):

I just delete the `node_module` folder and run `npm install` again. Its works for me.